# After Flashing kenrel my phone says empty or not supported sdcard

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, android-sdcard

I have tried to figure this out and I'm at a loss.

I am in the process or making a custom kernel for android and when I flash it it says my external sd card is empty or is not supported.

I have went the the kernel config and made sure file systems ( ext2, ext3, ext4, NTFS.) But still no dice.

When I plug my external sd card in a adapter and view on my computer I see all the files and even when I put it back into my phone and boot in recovery I can see all the files. Its just when I boot normally.

I also can flash my stock kernel recovery and I can see my sdcard again.

Which is why I think it's kernel related.

If anyone could help me I would really really appreciate it. I can't think of what I can change.

Thanks,

Zach

Comment: You should post here :http://android.stackexchange.com/ SO is a programming site

Comment: @Zach Can you provide the exact error message?

Comment: Hello again @SamProtsenko lol. It says "Sd card is Blank or has unsupported file-system" here is a screenshot on my phone ------ https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0iYPEw18PuiQkZFY3J2TVhNeFk/view?usp=docslist_api